# managedObjectContext func in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, core-data

I strive to understand Core Data implementation.

When I examined Core Data implementations I encountered codes as above

In AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
..


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

There is a property as 
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;

and there is a func as
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext

How it's create a relation between them, how/where it's call managedObjectContext func.

Comment: I think the issue less about `NSManagedObjectContext` and more about understanding the `@property` and `@synthesize`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/DeclaredProperty.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__managedObjectContext is an instance variable.

managedObjectContext is a getter method for __managedObjectContext. It allows you to get __managedObjectContext by, e.g., self.managedObjectContext.

Access of instance variable is usually done through its setter and getter methods.